# GAS Calling a function where the function name is in a variable

Tags: function, google-apps-script

I have a variable which determines which function to run, but I need to use multiple test and execute if statements. Is there a better way?

I have a menu system which produces an action code. Using this I can run any of a number (perhaps large number) of responses. I have, therefore, a long list of if statements:-

```
if(thisActionCode == "root")    {return root(e,thisCurrentUser,thisActionCode,veracity);}
if(thisActionCode == "worlds")  {return worlds(e,thisCurrentUser,thisActionCode,veracity);}
if(thisActionCode == "worldone"){return worldone(e,thisCurrentUser,thisActionCode,veracity);}
if(thisActionCode == "worldtwo"){return worldtwo(e,thisCurrentUser,thisActionCode,veracity);}
```

How can I run the function named in the variable just in one line? Is it even possible. There are many answers that come close but are imbedded in other things and I cannot figure out the bits that I need. Help please, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final code.

```
function fusebox(e,thisCurrentUser,thisActionCode)
  {
        calllog(thisCurrentUser,"fusebox - start",thisActionCode);

    // ask if the user is allowed to do this
    var veracity = verifyactioncode(thisCurrentUser,thisActionCode);

    // if the user is not permitted then show the main screen
    // this should never be executed as the user will not have the menu item to click
    if(veracity == "N/A")
      {
        calllog(thisCurrentUser,"fusebox - end",thisActionCode); return root(e,thisCurrentUser,thisActionCode);
      }

    // this will run the function for the selected menu item
    try
      {
        // using this[thisActionCode] was suggested by tanaike on my Stack Overflow question [GAS Calling a function where the function name is in a variable]
        // it works well
        calllog(thisCurrentUser,"fusebox - end",thisActionCode);return this[thisActionCode](e,thisCurrentUser,thisActionCode,veracity);
      }

    // if the menu item does not yet have a function named for it then say so
    catch(err)
      {
        return "<br><br><b>Response to this menu item has not been created yet, sorry.</b>"
      }

    // if all else fails - this should never be executed!
           calllog(thisCurrentUser,"fusebox - end",thisActionCode); return root(e,thisCurrentUser,thisActionCode,veracity);
  }
  
  // ---------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

In your script, how about the following modification using an object?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```js
if(thisActionCode == "root")    {return root(e,thisCurrentUser,thisActionCode,veracity);}
if(thisActionCode == "worlds")  {return worlds(e,thisCurrentUser,thisActionCode,veracity);}
if(thisActionCode == "worldone"){return worldone(e,thisCurrentUser,thisActionCode,veracity);}
if(thisActionCode == "worldtwo"){return worldtwo(e,thisCurrentUser,thisActionCode,veracity);}
```

##### To:

```js
const obj = { root, worlds, worldone, worldtwo };
if (thisActionCode in obj) {
  return obj[thisActionCode](e, thisCurrentUser, thisActionCode, veracity);
}

// If you want to proceed when "thisActionCode" is not included in "obj", please put your script below.
// do something.
```

- In this modification, when the value of `thisActionCode` is included in `obj`, the function of `thisActionCode` is run with the arguments of `e, thisCurrentUser, thisActionCode, veracity`.
- When you want to increase funcitons, please modify `const obj = { root, worlds, worldone, worldtwo };`.
- About `How can I run the function named in the variable just in one line?`, if the value of `thisActionCode` is always included in `obj`, I think that you might be able to use the following one line script.

  ```
    return ({ root, worlds, worldone, worldtwo })[thisActionCode](e, thisCurrentUser, thisActionCode, veracity);
  ```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the thoughts and suggestions. Using your **{ root, worlds, worldone, worldtwo };** still requires me to update the code each time I add a new function to call. I was hoping to just create the function and then call it through the value of the variable rather than to have to add to the code here as well. These will be options and sub options etc on a menu so there could be very many of them. I may experiment with your **return obj[thisActionCode](e, thisCurrentUser, thisActionCode, veracity);** to see if I can use this to do what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of:-
**if(thisActionCode == "root")    {return root(e,thisCurrentUser,thisActionCode,veracity);}**

I guess I want to do:-
**return [thisActionCode](e,thisCurrentUser,thisActionCode,veracity);**

But I get:-

**TypeError: [thisActionCode] is not a function (line 12, file "boxoffuses")**

More experimentation needed.

Comment: I can get a list of values to go into the obj = {   } like this:-

// grab the menu data block from the spreadsheet
    var spreadsheet       = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SHEETURL);
    var sheet             = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('permits');
    var int_uptally       = sheet.getRange("K4").getValue();
    var ar_menudatablock  = sheet.getRange(4,1,int_uptally,12).getValues();

Now I need to get the values from the arrayrange (ar_menudatablock) and create the obj from them.

Comment: @Jukebox Jory Thank you for replying. About `Using your { root, worlds, worldone, worldtwo }; still requires me to update the code each time I add a new function to call.`, in your situation, various function names are used. For example, when your function names are known, the functions can be automatically detected using it. For example, when you want to use the functions except for one function like `myFunction`, the functions except for `myFunctions` in Google Apps Script project. How about this?

Comment: Hi. Given your original idea which I like, **`const obj = { root, worlds, worldone, worldtwo };`**  how can I programmatically create this obj from my data. I have something like:- **`var ar_menudatablock  = sheet.getRange(4,1,int_uptally,12).getValues();`** which picks up the options all in one go. (More efficient that stepping through.) The goal is always data-driven rather than hard-coded.

Comment: @Jukebox Jory Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. What is `var ar_menudatablock  = sheet.getRange(4,1,int_uptally,12).getValues();` of `I have something like:- var ar_menudatablock  = sheet.getRange(4,1,int_uptally,12).getValues(); which picks up the options all in one go. (More efficient that stepping through.)`? For example, are the values of `ar_menudatablock` the function names you want to use? If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Hi. All of my function names are stored in a google sheet called **menuitems** and the list of which user can use which menu option are in **permits**. I have a function for each menu item. If the system gets large (unlikely I know) then I will have perhaps a hundred menu items and therefore a hundred functions. Doing a chain of if(){} statements to run the appropriate function will cause a huge delay each time the user clicks a link. I am trying to run the function by using a one line command where the function name is replaced with the value from the variable (in this case thisActionCode).

Comment: @Jukebox Jory Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your actual question. What is `All of my function names are stored in a google sheet called menuitems and the list of which user can use which menu option are in permits. I have a function for each menu item.`? I cannot understand the relationship between `var ar_menudatablock  = sheet.getRange(4,1,int_uptally,12).getValues();` and your reply. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide more information for understand your actual question?

Comment: @Jukebox Jory I have 3 questions. 1. What is `var ar_menudatablock  = sheet.getRange(4,1,int_uptally,12).getValues();`? 2. What is the relationship between `var ar_menudatablock  = sheet.getRange(4,1,int_uptally,12).getValues();` and `All of my function names are stored in a google sheet called menuitems and the list of which user can use which menu option are in permits. I have a function for each menu item.`? 3. Are the values of `ar_menudatablock` the function names you want to use?

Comment: @Jukebox Jory I deeply apologize for my very very poor English skill. But, I would like to support you. So, if you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Hi. I have a google sheet which lists who can do what. For example **fred.bloggs** can run the **worlds** menu item. There may be many people and menu menu items. Once the user has clicked on the menu item (`https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfy..jDE/exec?actioncode=worlds`) it does a **doGet()** with the value from the menu in the **actioncode** field. I want to run the appropriate **function(){}** directly from the variable name **actioncode** rather than to have to test against a list of possible function names.

Comment: @Jukebox Jory Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. From your reply, unfortunately, I couldn't understand all 3 answers to my 3 questions. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: @Jukebox Jory About your reply, I have 4 new questions. 1. What is `For example fred.bloggs can run the worlds menu item.`? 2. What is `Once the user has clicked on the menu item (https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfy..jDE/exec?actioncode=taskmanager) it does a doGet() with the value from the menu in the actioncode field.`? 3. What is `I want to run the appropriate function(){} directly from the variable name actioncode rather than to have to test against a list of possible function names.`? 4. What is `the variable name actioncode`?

Comment: @Jukebox Jory I deeply apologize for my very very poor English skill. But, I would like to support you. In the current stage, can you provide 7 answers to my 7 questions to correctly understand your actual question? So, if you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Hi. I think it best to concentrate on the one line I am having trouble with. **`if(thisActionCode == "worlds")  {return worlds(e,thisCurrentUser,thisActionCode,veracity);}`** I want to genericise this so the word "worlds" is not in the code. It becomes **`return [thisActionCode](e,thisCurrentUser,thisActionCode,veracity);`** but this is not the right syntax. It is always better to drive things from data than to hard code things.

Comment: @Jukebox Jory Thank you for replying. From your reply, if the function of `worlds` is included in the same Google Apps Script project, I think that `return [thisActionCode](e,thisCurrentUser,thisActionCode,veracity);` can be modified to `return this[thisActionCode](e,thisCurrentUser,thisActionCode,veracity);`. `thisActionCode` is required to be valid function name. How about this? But, I cannot know your actual situation. So, if this didn't work, can I ask you about the detail of your actual script? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Thanks very much. I think this is the solution. No errors and it works.

Comment: @Jukebox Jory About `Thanks very much. I think this is the solution. No errors and it works.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer